# UWP progress ring activity

Tags: progress-bar, uwp

I am trying to hide the progress ring as soon as the stuff on my page loads completely, but I don't know where and how to set its set active property to false.

```
Progress.IsActive;
```

where should I use this line of code?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided much information on how you are loading data on your page, but I assume you are doing it asynchronously.

If you're doing it all sequentially, you can deactivate the progress ring at the end:

```
public async void InitializeData()
{
    TextBox1.Text = await GetData1();
    TextBox2.Text = await GetData2();
    TextBox3.Text = await GetData3();
    // ...

    Progress.IsActive = false;
}
```

If you're loading the data in parallel, then you should collect or awaitable tasks in a single array and await them all:

```
public async void InitializeData()
{
    var loadingTasks = new Task[]
    {
        GetData1(),
        GetData2(),
        GetData3()
        // ...
    };

    await Task.WhenAll(loadingTasks);

    Progress.IsActive = false;
}
```

In this case you would assign the loaded data to controls inside the individual `GetData` methods.